# Reshaping a data based one two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr, reshape

I have a data like this :

```
df<-structure(list(id = c(13186082L, 13186082L, 15186082L, 15186082L, 
32186082L, 32186082L, 24186085L, 24186085L), freq1 = c("socialinteraction2", 
"who", "socialinteraction2", "who", "socialinteraction2", "who", 
"socialinteraction2", "who"), Response = c("2", "a", "1", "b", 
"3", "a", "4", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

```
         id              freq1 Response
1 13186082 socialinteraction2        2
2 13186082                who        a
3 15186082 socialinteraction2        1
4 15186082                who        b
5 32186082 socialinteraction2        3
6 32186082                who        a
7 24186085 socialinteraction2        4
8 24186085                who        c
```

I want to reshape it in a way that selects the "Response" when
freq1="who" and repeat the number of "Response"  when freq1="socialinteraction2" in the way like this:

```
                 From To
1  socialinteraction2  a
2  socialinteraction2  a
3  socialinteraction2  b
4  socialinteraction2  a
5  socialinteraction2  a
6  socialinteraction2  a
7  socialinteraction2  c
8  socialinteraction2  c
9  socialinteraction2  c
10 socialinteraction2  c
```

So, for instance, for the first Id, I want to make two columns. For "to" when "freq1" is who selects "a" 2 times and all the "from" values will be "socialinteraction2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for:

```
df<-structure(list(id = c(13186082L, 13186082L, 15186082L, 15186082L, 32186082L, 32186082L, 24186085L, 24186085L), 
                   freq1 = c("socialinteraction2", "who", "socialinteraction2", "who", "socialinteraction2", "who", 
                                                                                 "socialinteraction2", "who"), 
                   Response = c("2", "a", "1", "b", "3", "a", "4", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


#separat socialinteraction2 and who into 2 columns
output <-df %>% pivot_wider(names_from= freq1, values_from = Response)

#create the repeating values
repeats <- rep(output$who, times=as.integer(output$socialinteraction2))

data.frame(From=c("socialinteraction2"), To=repeats)
```